# ESP32 Core panic'ed when accessing global variable

Tags: c++, esp32, platformio

**Esp32 reboots when trying to print out "data". Why?**

I'm trying to save all logs to single string to be displayed on ESPUI, but this simple code is rebooting my esp.

**board:** esp32dev

**framework:** arduino

**platform:** espressif32@3.5.0

**ide:** VSCODE

LoggerFactory.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
class LoggerFactory
{
private:
        void Log(String prefix, String severity ,String message);

public:
        LoggerFactory();
        ~LoggerFactory();
        void Debug(String prefix, String message);
        void Info(String prefix, String message);
        void Warning(String prefix, String message);
        void Error(String prefix, String message);
        String data = "some data";
};

LoggerFactory::LoggerFactory()
{
}

LoggerFactory::~LoggerFactory()
{
}
void LoggerFactory::Debug(String prefix, String message){
    Log(prefix, "Debug", message);
}
void LoggerFactory::Info(String prefix, String message){
    Log(prefix, "Info", message);
}
void LoggerFactory::Warning(String prefix, String message){
    Log(prefix, "Warning", message);
}
void LoggerFactory::Error(String prefix, String message){
    Log(prefix, "Error", message);
}
void LoggerFactory::Log(String prefix, String severity ,String message){
    String compiledmessage = String(millis()/1000) + " | " + prefix + " | " + severity + " | " + message;
    Serial.println(compiledmessage);
    Serial.print(data);
}
```

Logger.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Logging/LoggerFactory.h>

class Logger
{
private:
    void Log(String prefix, String severity ,String message);
    String _prefix;
    LoggerFactory _factory;
public:
  Logger(String prefix);
    ~Logger();
  void Debug(String message);
  void Info(String message);
  void Warning(String message);
  void Error(String message);
  void Iniciialize(LoggerFactory& factory);
};

Logger::Logger(String prefix){
    _prefix = prefix;
}
Logger::~Logger(){}

void Logger::Iniciialize(LoggerFactory& factory){
    _factory = factory;
}
void Logger::Debug(String message){
    _factory.Debug(_prefix,message);
}
void Logger::Info(String message){
   _factory.Info(_prefix,message);
}
void Logger::Warning(String message){
    _factory.Warning(_prefix,message);
}
void Logger::Error( String message){
  _factory.Error(_prefix,message);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
LoggerFactory factory;
Logger OTAlogger("OTA");

void setup(){
Serial.begin(115200);
OTAlogger.Iniciialize(factory);
factory.Info("Main","Booting");
OTAlogger.Info("Ready");
}

void loop(){}
```

ESP exception:

```
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
0 | Main | Info | Booting
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400dd8fb  PS      : 0x00060730  A0      : 0x800dbd50  A1      : 0x3ffb1e30  
A2      : 0x3ffbdbd8  A3      : 0x00004154  A4      : 0x0000b554  A5      : 0x3ffb8be6  
A6      : 0x00000067  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x0000001a  A9      : 0x3ff40000  
A10     : 0x0000007f  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x3ffb8998  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000010  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00004154  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400dd8fb:0x3ffb1e30 0x400dbd4d:0x3ffb1e50 0x400dc191:0x3ffb1e70 0x400d1553:0x3ffb1e90 0x400d167d:0x3ffb1ee0 0x400d1a2d:0x3ffb1f30  0x400dde1e:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40089a56:0x3ffb1fd0
  #0  0x400dd8fb:0x3ffb1e30 in uartWriteBuf at C:/Users/kubap/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32@3.10006.210326/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-uart.c:464
  #1  0x400dbd4d:0x3ffb1e50 in HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:/Users/kubap/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32@   3.10006.210326/cores/esp32/HardwareSerial.cpp:190
  #2  0x400dc191:0x3ffb1e70 in Print::write(char const*, unsigned int) at C:/Users/kubap/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32@3.10006.210326/cores/esp32/Print.cpp:261
  (inlined by) Print::print(String const&) at C:/Users/kubap/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32@3.10006.210326/cores/esp32/Print.cpp:84
  #3  0x400d1553:0x3ffb1e90 in LoggerFactory::Log(String, String, String) at src/Logging/LoggerFactory.cpp:32
  #4  0x400d167d:0x3ffb1ee0 in LoggerFactory::Info(String, String) at src/Logging/LoggerFactory.cpp:32
  #5  0x400d1a2d:0x3ffb1f30 in setup() at src/main.cpp:19 (discriminator 2)
  #6  0x400dde1e:0x3ffb1fb0 in loopTask(void*) at C:/Users/kubap/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32@3.10006.210326/cores/esp32/main.cpp:18
  #7  0x40089a56:0x3ffb1fd0 in vPortTaskWrapper at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-   idf/components/freertos/port.c:355 (discriminator 1)

Rebooting...
```

**Does anyone no why is it doing this? It is bug or feature or language limitation?**

Comment: What is 'iniciialize?'

Comment: My function in class Logger